# Circular reference in JsonSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, jsonserializer

I have a list of objects with links to each other to get a double linked chain. Although I marked the links not to be considered in the serializer I get the message

> "A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a
> cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth
> of 64. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on
> JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles. Path:
> $.pSuccessor.pSuccessor.pSuccessor.pSuccessor.pSuccessor.pSuccessor.pPredecessor.pSuccessor.pPredecessor.
> ... .pPredecessor.Location.IsEmpty."

The objects are defined in this way:

```
  public class BObject : Panel, ISerializable, ICloneable
  {
    public eObjectType typObject;
    ...
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual BObject pSuccessor
    {
      get { return null; }
      set { }
    }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual BObject pPredecessor
    {
      get { return null; }
      set { }
    }
    ...
  }

  [Serializable]
  public partial class DvObject : BObject, ISerializable
  {
    [NonSerialized]
    [ScriptIgnore]
    protected DvObject pPrevious;
    [NonSerialized]
    [ScriptIgnore]
    protected DvObject pNext;
    ...
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public override BObject pSuccessor
    {
      get { return pNext; }
      set { pNext = (RvmComponent)value; }
    }

    public override BObject pPredecessor
    {
      get { return pPrevious; }
      set
      {
        ...
        pPrevious = (DvObject)value;
        ...
      }
    }
  }
```

The code processing the serialization where the error occurs is:

```
  foreach (BObject obj in lobj)
  {
    String jsonObj = JsonSerializer.Serialize(lobj, options);
  }
```

How is it possible to reach that the `JsonSerializer` ignors the other linked objects and doesn't try to serialize them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are just looking for:

```
[JsonIgnore]
```